# node js app works locally but display weirdly on heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku

**solved**

I've got nodejs app that works fine locally
[how it's suppose to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKRIr.png)

but when run with heroku all I've got was angular braces

```
Total Registered Devices : {{deviceCount}}
{{ device.deviceName }} 
IMEI : {{ device.deviceId }} 
delete
```

with no error on logs

```
2017-05-17T14:00:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user shira@bd-el.com 
2017-05-17T14:00:52.540172+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user shira@bd-el.com 
2017-05-17T14:00:52.540172+00:00 app[api]: Deploy d1f297f by user shira@bd-el.com 
2017-05-17T14:00:53.110060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting 
2017-05-17T14:00:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-05-17T14:00:55.758955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js` 
2017-05-17T14:01:00.294554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting     to up 2017-05-17T14:01:00.794336+00:00 app[web.1]: 7163 is the magic port
2017-05-17T14:01:01.254442+00:00 app[web.1]: db is open
2017-05-17T14:01:01.258895+00:00 app[web.1]: db is mongodb://heroku_090x9gxv:rkk64dlhd8mifkd08og359ti44@ds143181.mlab.com:43181/heroku_090x9gxv 
2017-05-17T14:02:04.932689+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-stream-95096.herokuapp.com request_id=753b228e-ed70-474e-a0f1-8c3001ba980f fwd="185.3.147.160" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=80ms status=200 bytes=2732 protocol=https 
2017-05-17T14:02:05.197980+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/main.js" host=afternoon-stream-95096.herokuapp.com request_id=13faf8b3-8c86-4e2f-9787-2912b6b50816 fwd="185.3.147.160" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=3211 protocol=https
```

and my package.json file is-

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-web-app1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "NodejsWebApp1",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "ddfps"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.9",
    "morgan": "^1.8.1",
    "node-gcm": "^0.14.6",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.4"
  }
}
```

**edit:** console logs

```
> Blocked loading mixed active content
> “http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons”[Learn More]
> afternoon-stream-95096.herokuapp.com Blocked loading mixed active
> content
> “http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css”[Learn
> More] afternoon-stream-95096.herokuapp.com Blocked loading mixed
> active content
> “http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js”[Learn
> More] afternoon-stream-95096.herokuapp.com Blocked loading mixed
> active content
> “http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js”[Learn
> More] afternoon-stream-95096.herokuapp.com Blocked loading mixed
> active content
> “http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js”[Learn
> More] afternoon-stream-95096.herokuapp.com Blocked loading mixed
> active content
> “http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js”[Learn
> More] afternoon-stream-95096.herokuapp.com Blocked loading mixed
> active content
> “http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js”[Learn
> More] afternoon-stream-95096.herokuapp.com ReferenceError: angular is
> not defined[Learn More]
```

or in short - angular is not defined.
what could cause the problem?

p.s I've got the exact same error when ran through cloud.9

**edit 2 - solution**
angular was not defined because it's href was to http and heroku runs on https which caused the packages not to be loaded.
I removed the 'http:' from the hrefs and that solved the problem.

Comment: how about console logs?

Comment: you have to show us more to see what's the issue